# How to add a firefox shortcut to open an addon

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Similar to chrome chrome://extensions/shortcuts is there any way to define a shortcut on FF to popup a addon in the toolbar?

Comment: For my concrete case is the lastpass addon. Is there any way to check if this option already exits?

Comment: Too bad if this must be set on the developer side. I think this should be a layer on the browser / client side, like in chrome... Maybe I should fill a support ticket in FF instead.